# Git для sublime text 2 не работает

Tags: git, sublime-text

Установил на редактор sublime text2 плагин git. После инициализации рабочей директории через командную строку git(через sublime так же не работает) перехожу в sublime, но при попытке добавить файл для отслеживания выдает ошибку

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

**без** *sublime* добавьте файл(ы) в индекс и сделайте первый коммит вручную:

```
$ git add файл ...
$ git commit -m 'first commit'
```

после этого будет сформирован `refs/heads/master` и всё должно заработать.

объяснение, например, [здесь (англ.)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12887486/4827341). там речь про *shell*, но механизм и причина, насколько я понимаю, те же самые.

Comment: `$ git add файл ...` даже на эту команду выдается тоже сообщение - **fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.**

Comment: попробуйте пересоздать репозиторий: 1. удалите каталог с репозиторием. он находится в текущем каталоге и называется `.git`: `$ rm -rf .git`. 2. создайте репозиторий заново: `$ git init`. // а затем уже добавляйте файлы в индекс и делайте коммит.

Comment: команду `$ rm -rf .git` попробовал, вот что он мне написал - `fatal: pathspec '.git' did not match any files`. Рабочую директорию инициализировал через командную строку git, так как sublime тоже ругается при попытке сделать инициализацию через него.

Comment: @user189379, у вас, видимо, ms/windows. и вы, видимо, пользуетесь какой-то «обёрткой» для выполненения команд git-а. `rm ...` — это я подразумевал не команду `git rm ...`, а уделения каталога `.git` из *файловой системы*. не помню, как удаляются каталоги в ms/dos, попробуйте воспользоваться каким-нибудь файловым менеджером. например, «проводником ms/windows».

Comment: через командную строку git-a удалось удалить, затем через sublime инициализировал. Добавить и закомитить файл так и не удалось выдает ошибку `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: @user189379, уточните, пожалуйста: 1. какой операционной системой вы пользуетесь? 2. какие действия вы выполняете для создания репозитория?

Comment: ОС windows 7. Если через sublime, то 1- Через **меню->tools->git->int** инициализирую рабочую директорию 2-Через **меню->tools->git->This File->add** добавляю файл для отслеживания 3-Через **меню->tools->git->thisFile->quick commit current file** пытаюсь сделать комит.

Comment: @user189379, я с самого начала вёл речь о том, что, **прежде** чем пользоваться sublime, надо **без** sublime: 1. добавить файлы в индекс. 2. сделать commit.

Comment: @user189379, добавил уточнение в ответ.

Comment: извините, я вас сразу не совсем понял. Вы были правы, после того как я сделал первый комит через командную строку git-a все заработало в sublime.Спасибо! А не подскажите с чем это связано?

Comment: связано с тем, что sublime некорректно работает с **пустым** репозиторием. если у этой программы есть баг-трекер, то, вероятно, имеет смысл послать баг-репорт. а если вы за право её испольвания ещё и деньги заплатили, то справедливо будет потребовать их возврата.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по ошибке - sublime говорит что в папке не инициализирован гит. 
Не работал с гитом в сублайме, но попробуйте открыть через file->open folder вашу директорию с кодом, может заработает.

Comment: Попробовал открыть папку с рабочими файлами, результат тот же. В обход sublime через саму командную строку git все работает...